# Software recommendations stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Would it be worth having the new [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site added as an option in the close option "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" dialogue?

I am aware the site is still in beta of course, but maybe this could drive adoption and a full launch of that site?

Comment: @gnat I prefer [status-declined] for these types of requests, because [status-deferred] implies we will revisit them sometime soon(ish). However, with beta sites the reality is that graduation might take a year or two, or not happen at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's standard policy to not have beta sites as migration targets. This is to allow the site to develop by itself during beta and define a solid community. If there are **exceptional** questions that are off-topic here and on-topic there, moderators can migrate to any site on the network, so you can flag it. I wouldn't expect too many migrations, though.

Comment: Fair enough! For you last statement, why not? And if that site comes out of beta, I guess that would be the best time to request this feature? seems a no brainer at that point then?

Comment: Until they have a good, solid definition and examples of what they consider to be high quality or exceptional answers, i personally don't feel comfortable migrating anything there. If they get out of beta, this should be revisited

Comment: @Ozz When SR gets out of beta, the first thing we'll have to do is take a look at our [migration stats](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (10K+ link). If we are sending a lot of questions to SR at that time, adding a migration path would indeed be a no brainer. A few more details on the overall policy and process on [Tim Post's answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/5780/25936) on a related question.

Comment: thanks @ThomasOwens

Comment: thanks @YannisRizos