# Should there be a migration path to Software Recommendations?

Tags: discussion, migration

[Software Recommendations is graduating](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298) and will soon be a non-beta site!

[There is a question on their meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2307) about being a migration target: they are asking about other sites such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/) having a migration path to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) did not come up there: while I would expect some other sites to have more recommendation questions, we do see some of these questions on Programmers and we have a few open slots for migration targets.

Once Software Recommendations is fully graduated to a regular site, should Programmers have a migration path to it?

---

#### See Also

- [Software recommendations stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464) - asked and answered before the graduation announcement.
- [Revisiting what is on topic, with respect to new sites: Open Source, Law, and Software Recommendations](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7539) - software recommendations are *still* off-topic here.

Comment: SR mod here, not a regular on Progse. Can you post a representative sample of questions that might potentially be migrated, so we get an idea of whether they'd meet our guidelines?

Comment: @Gilles given that such questions are off-topic here, those questions get closed and deleted rather quickly making it difficult to find links. Personally, I have never even flagged one for moderator migration to SoftwareRecs.SE due to quality. I think the votes on the answers to this question back up that assertion with community consensus.

Comment: @Gilles I found a single software recommendation question in the "recently deleted" list and added it to the "don't migrate" answer if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 9):

Software Recommendations moderator here. We're [technically a non-beta site *now*](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/46) - which means moderators aren't discouraged from migrating questions to us any more.

I would be against adding SR to Programmers' migration target list. Not that I don't trust y'all, but we have [some *really strict* requirements](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) for questions.

That said, if you take the time to read those requirements, and you happen to see a question come through here (or any other site where software recommendation questions are off topic), feel free to throw an 'other' flag on it, asking your moderators to throw it over.

It's much easier for us (SR) to train a few dozen moderators in what is on-topic than a whole community... that isn't even our own. If we start getting a large number of (good) migrations coming from a site, I would absolutely be in favor of being a target on their list.

But I'd like a site to prove that its *moderators* can give us good content before we open it up to its *users*.

Comment: I had not realized the subtle difference. SoftwareRecs has the beta style but no "beta" after the name. That probably has something to do with the [recent announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) about graduation changes.

Answer (score 6):

No, there should not be a migration path.

Many of the questions asking for software recommendations fail to meet quality guidelines for the Software Recommendations site and cannot be salvaged through editing. An open migration path will only cause additional problems and grief with the Software Recommendations community.

Example questions supporting not having a migration path:

[Is there any software for a pdf auto renaming pc software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/300141) (10k link)

> I scan and rename proof of deliveries daily for my company I work for.
>   I am looking for some software that I can set up a template on it to
>   mark areas of text on the pdf I scan and save it so in future it will
>   detect the text of the marked areas of the any future documents I scan
>   and rename the saved file as the text from the marked ares.. e.g. the
>   date the proof of delivery was made and the recognition numbers the
>   document contains like out will be an i/o number and a M10057474
>   number. I'd be so appreciative if someone could lead me to the right
>   software please.

Comment: My opinion on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/300141 : it isn't so bad, but not answerable as is. It has a precise usage scenario but lacks some critical requirements, mainly the OS that the software should run on. It's a textbook candidate for closing with a comment that the question should be re-asked on SR with the missing information.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there should be a migration path.

Programmers receives enough of these questions to warrant an open migration path. This will allow the askers to receive quality answers from a community where such questions are on-topic.

As with any migration, poor-quality questions should either be edited before migration if they are salvageable, or should simply be closed and not migrated.